# Grad pytorch used for Langevin Dynamics sampling

Tags: python, pytorch, sampling, autograd

I am new to pytorch and I am training a model using Langevin Dynamics. In my code I need to sample points using Langevin Dynamics to approximate two functions f1 and f2.
I have created a class which performs the sampling and I am instantiating two classes to approximate f1 and f2 respectively.
If I train my model approximating both f1 and f2 it seems that the model is converging twice as faster as if I train the model just approximating f1. It seems there is some sort of interaction between the points sampled even if there should be none.
Can someone with better knowledge of pytorch and autograd help me understand what is going on?
Thank you all in advance!

This is the code of the class which performs the Langevin Dynamics sampling:

```
class LangevinSampler():
  def __init__(self, args, seed, mdp):
    self.ld_steps = args.ld_steps
    self.step_size = args.step_size
    self.mdp=MDP(args)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)

  def energy_gradient(self, log_prob, x): 
    # copy original data that doesn’t require grads!
    x_grad = x.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True).cuda()
    # calculate the gradient
    x_i_grad = torch.autograd.grad(log_prob(x_grad).sum(), [x_grad], retain_graph=True)[0]
    return x_i_grad

  def sample(self, log_prob, num_samples, iter=None):
    x_init = self.mdp.q.rsample(sample_shape = torch.Size([num_samples])).cuda()
    x_sample = x_init
    if iter == None or iter > 0:
      for i in range(self.ld_steps):
          grad_energy = self.energy_gradient(log_prob, x_sample)
          ## Sample epsilon ~ Normal(0, step_size**0.5)
          epsilon = torch.randn_like(grad_energy)
          ## LD step
          x_sample = x_sample.cuda() + 0.5 * self.step_size * grad_energy + self.step_size**0.5 * epsilon
          
    return x_sample
```

Comment: I think there might be some gradient accumulations problems but I can not find a solution